# OverflowException thrown when computing a percentage

Tags: c#, exception, overflow

I have code that takes as an argument a Dictionary and returns a Dictionary.

The code computes the sum of all the double values and uses the sum to compute what percentage each value is of the sum.  It returns a new Dictionary with the percentages concatenated onto the keys.

There are some OverflowExceptions recorded in my web server's Event Viewer.  The log records that the exception occurs on the following code `Decimal percentage = (Decimal) (pDataPoints[key] / sum * 100);`  It says that the exception occurs when casting the value to a decimal.

What edge case could I be missing?

```
public static Dictionary<string, double> addPercentagesToDataPointLabels(Dictionary<string, double> pDataPoints)
{
Dictionary<string, double> valuesToReturn = new Dictionary<string, double>();

// First, compute the sum of the data point values
double sum = 0;
foreach (double d in pDataPoints.Values)
{
    sum += d;
}

// Now, compute the percentages using the sum and add them to the new labels.
foreach (string key in pDataPoints.Keys)
{
    string newKey = key;
    Decimal percentage = (Decimal) (pDataPoints[key] / sum * 100);
    percentage = Math.Round(percentage, ChartingValues.DIGITS_AFTER_DECIMAL_POINT);
    newKey += " " + percentage.ToString() + "%";
    valuesToReturn.Add(newKey, pDataPoints[key]);
}

return valuesToReturn;
}
```

Comment: I can help you crash yours C# code with a `DivideByZeroException` `0/0` I'm not so good with `OverflowException` but you're in the right place now...

Comment: @Rice Flour Cookies - btw, why are you converting percentage to Decimal. Wouldn't it be better if you stay with doubles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
addPercentagesToDataPointLabels(new Dictionary<string, double>(){{"a", 0}});
```

Like gdoron said, you divide by 0. But it throws an exception only for ints. For floating point numbers, it results in `Double.Infinity`. It then tries to convert infinity to decimal.

Comment: Okay, I've got it figured out now.  If the values passed in are all 0, then it divides by 0.  However, 0/0 is NaN when both 0 values are doubles.  The OverflowException is thrown when NaN is cast to a Decimal.  I think that this may be a flaw in the .net framework that the exception message did not suggest that OverflowException could be caused by casting NaN to a Decimal

Comment: Ok I got to the same conclusion but the other way round, the dictionary contains a `double.NaN` but I didnt pick up that the same would happen if the dictionary only has 1 input and its zero.

Answer (score 3):

```
pDataPoints[key] / sum * 100
```

This computation gives you result that is too small or too large to store in decimal. You may catch this exception and check what is the value of this expression.
My suggestion (since I cannot tell what values you're expecting):

```
double percentageValue = pDataPoints[key] / sum * 100;
try
{
    Decimal percentage = (Decimal) percentageValue;
}
catch (OverflowException exception)
{
    //log percentageValue
    throw;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The max value of a `decimal` is 79,228,162,514,264,337,593,543,950,335.  The max value of a `double` (your input value) is 1.7976931348623157E+308.  Presumably some of your input values (or at least, the result of `pDataPoints[key] / sum * 100`) result in a value larger than the max decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Being that you're only actually calculating a percentage, its pretty hard to come up with a true number that makes that percentage calculation fall outside of the range `decimal.MinValue < v < decimal.MaxValue`.

There is, however, a value which will always cause this error `double.NaN`.

If you pass this dictionary to your method:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string,double>(){
            {"A",2},
            {"B",2}
        };
```

You quite correctly get the result:

```
Key:A 50% Value:2
Key:B 50% Value:2
```

However change that to this input:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string,double>(){
            {"A",double.NaN},
            {"B",2}
        };
```

and the result is:

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.

Could this be your edge case? Whatever generates the input dictionary is producing a `NaN`.

A live example for you to demonstarte the above is here: http://rextester.com/RRQT60265